# Django and mod_wsgi python versions?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, python-3.6

Can Django run on Python 3.6.x while mod_wsgi is create using Python 2.7.x? thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. This is explained in various places in the mod_wsgi documentation. Your mod_wsgi will need to be compiled against Python 3.6. If your system packages are out of date, as they pretty well are for all OS distributions, uninstall them and compile mod_wsgi from source code yourself.

Is suggested you use the `pip` method for building mod_wsgi against version of Python you need and then either use `mod_wsgi-express`, or configure system Apache to use the `mod_wsgi.so` built by `pip install` by using `mod_wsgi-express module-config` to get the configuration to include in the system Apache.

See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi